# How to check periodically using Test-Connection few computer and start copy files whenever they apper online and keep checking on onfline ones?

Tags: powershell, automation

I need some help/advice in writing a PowerShell script that checks **Test-Connection** for few computers and whenever computer appears online start copying assigned files to their shared folder PATH. How do I write it down? Mostly I'm interest in *"checking online"* part as I have function that copy a file I want to a shared PATH I want (copyBuild $X $toFilip). Probably using While loop  ( (Test-Connection  -Quiet ) -eq $True) {}?

Shared folders are not accessible when their computer is shutdown so I need to come up with something. The thing is that I want to skip the computers that are offline and start copying it to the computers that are online and whenever the offline -eq online start copying to them as well. And when every copyBuild is finished then exit/finish the script. I would appreciate any help with basic logic or some articles/posts that will help me write it down. Thanks in adv

```
`#revision number changing every day
$svnRev = "123123"

#path from where I pull my file (usually only one fie that is around 70-80GB
$platform_X_PC = "D:\Source\X\$svnRev\"
$platform_Y_PC = "D:\Source\Y\$svnRev\PC"
$platform_Y_Linux = "D:\Source\Y\$svnRev\Linux"


#Team members shared folder path I copy the file to
$filip = "\\Desktop\Filip\"
$neo = "\\Desktop\Neo\"
$morpheus = "\\Desktop\Morpheus\"

#main function 
Function copyBuild {
    param(
        [string]$platform,
        [string]$qa
    )

    $qaName = $qa.split("\")[-2]
    $platformName = $platform.split("\")[-1]
    $projectName = $platform.split("\")[-3]
    
    Write-Host "Copying files for:------------------"$qaName"---------------------"
    Write-Host "Project: "$projectName 
    Write-Host "From: "$platform
#If its X project I want to go to different folder, same with Y
    if ($projectName -eq "X"){
        Write-Host "Dest: "$qa$projectName\$svnRev
        robocopy $platform $qa$projectName\$svnRev /E /DCOPY:DAT /R:1 /W:5 /J /MT:32 /LOG+:"C:\Users\User\Documents\Robocopy_Logs\$projectName.log"
        Write-Host "Fnished copying" $projectName" build "$svnRev
    }elseif ($projectName -eq "Y"){
        Write-Host "Dest: "$qa$svnRev\$platformName
        robocopy $platform $qa$svnRev\$platformName /E /DCOPY:DAT /R:1 /W:5 /J /MT:32 /LOG+:"C:\Users\User\Documents\Robocopy_Logs\$platformName.log"
        Write-Host "Fnished copying" $projectName $platformName" build "$svnRev
    }else{
        Write-Host "Cant find the project"
    }
}
```

#copy build--> this the part where I want to check if I start copyBuild computer is "on" & shared folder is accessible. When for example: copyBuild $platform_X_PC $filip is on and copy is finished then keep checking on the rest and copy them whenever the destination unc PATH is available

```
copyBuild $platform_X_PC $filip
copyBuild $platform_Y_PC $neo
copyBuild $platform_Y_Linux $morpheus
```

PS keeping their computer on all day is not an option for now.

PS_2 Not sure if it's a good solution/approach to my needs. I'm willing to try something else as well

Comment: Welcome to SO, Filip. Please review the information at https://stackoverflow.com/help to understand how SO works. SO helps programmers make source code work. If there is no source code, it is likely to be considered off-topic for SO. Off-topic questions often get downvotes and votes to close. Please copy and paste, as text, the source code you are trying to make work into the question.

Answer (score 0):

if u need only a test-connection:

```
$hostname = Get-Content c:\powershell\ip.csv #for example, i'm using csv
$test_connect = foreach ($ip in $hostname) {

  if (Test-Connection $ip -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Quiet) {
    #Your function could be here
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Lite, I will definitely give it a go. I wonder why foreach is assigned to variable $test_connect? Is this something on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

IMPROVED VERSION:

```
$ComputerList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@(
    '127.0.0.11'
    'remote.address'
    'computerName'
    '127.0.0.1'
)


while ($ComputerList.Count) {
    $ComputerList | ForEach-Object -AsJob -Parallel {
        "Testing $_"
        if (Test-Connection -TargetName $_ -Ping -Count 1 -Quiet) {
            $TempVar = $using:ComputerList
            [void]$TempVar.Remove($_)
            "Removed $_"
        }
        else {
            "$_ does not answer"
        }
    } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job 
    Start-Sleep 1   
}
```

OLD AND BUSTED

```
$ComputerList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@(
    '127.0.0.11'
    'remote.address'
    'computerName'
    '127.0.0.1'
)

while ($ComputerList.Count) {
    $ComputerList | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        Write-Verbose "Testing $_"
        if (Test-Connection -TargetName $_ -Ping -Count 1 -Quiet) {
            $TempVar = $using:ComputerList
            [void]$TempVar.Remove($_)
            Write-Verbose "Removed $_"
        }
    } 
    Start-Sleep 1   
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sirtao Can I use only 'computer-name' for the test-connection like this:
$ComputerList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@(
    'DESKTOP-373FQ14',
    'DESKTOP-373FQ14'
)

Comment: Also I'm not sure where I should put my copyBuild function?

Comment: First comment: yes. Second comment: inside the  `if(test-connection)` scriptblock